# Reducing the amount of alternations without exponentially increasing the runtime?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity, advice-and-nonuniformity

Let $\mathsf{AltTime}(g(n), f(n))$ denote the class of languages that are solvable by an alternating machine using $f(n)$ time and $g(n)$ alternations.

Is there anything known about the following relation:
$$\exists f(n)\ \exists g(n)\ \exists h(n)<g(n):\mathsf{AltTime}(g(n),f(n))\subset \mathsf{AltTime}(h(n),2^{o(f(n))})/2^{o(n)}$$

I.e. how much smaller than $g(n)$ can $h(n)$ be (if at all) and at what (asymptotically) smallest $f(n)$ it holds.

Perhaps, something is also known about the relation with a smaller advice string or without an advice at all?

Comment: Do you allow $f(n) < n$?

Comment: @RyanWilliams The motivation for this is that *if* for some class $C=DTIME(f(n))$ the hierarchy $C^{PH}$ collapses, then this relation is true for $h(n)=g(n)-k$ for any fixed $k$, but this relation is a weaker statement.